# liferay disable import users after login or check existing users in some groups

Tags: ldap, liferay

I work with liferay-5.2.3 and I integrated  LDAP

using this configuration :

in **portal-ext.properties**  I make this lines :

```
ldap.import.method=group
system.community.roles=TestGr
```

and in liferay I make this configuration :

[image]

[image]

[image]

I activated the authentication using ldap .

I created two groups in LDAP :

**TestGroup1  and TestGroup2**

User import is periodic every hour As shown in the configuration

I tried to create Four users in ldap :

**user1   under testGroup1**

**user2  under  testGroup2**

**user3 , user4  out of the two previous groups**

Import of users is done correctly  : only **user1 and user2**  will be create in the database of liferay .

The problem is when I tried to authenticate with **user3**

I found that the **user3** is created in the liferay database

Despite the fact that the **user3** does not exist in the two groups **TestGroup1  and TestGroup2**

I think that the  solution is to disable import users from ldap after login or also check existing users in some groups before the import ( Which exists in the configuration ).

**Updated :**

this is the code of **LDAPAuth** class :

```
package com.liferay.portal.security.auth;

import com.liferay.portal.NoSuchUserException;
import com.liferay.portal.PasswordExpiredException;
import com.liferay.portal.UserLockoutException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Log;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogFactoryUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.Validator;
import com.liferay.portal.model.User;
import com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.security.pwd.PwdEncryptor;
import com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.util.PrefsPropsUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.util.PropsValues;
import com.liferay.portlet.admin.util.OmniadminUtil;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;
import javax.naming.ldap.Control;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;

public class LDAPAuth
  implements Authenticator
{
  public static final String AUTH_METHOD_BIND = "bind";
  public static final String AUTH_METHOD_PASSWORD_COMPARE = "password-compare";
  public static final String RESULT_PASSWORD_RESET = "2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.4";
  public static final String RESULT_PASSWORD_EXP_WARNING = "2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.5";
  private static Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(LDAPAuth.class);

  public int authenticateByEmailAddress(long companyId, String emailAddress, String password, Map<String, String[]> headerMap, Map<String, String[]> parameterMap)
    throws AuthException
  {
    try
    {
      return authenticate(companyId, emailAddress, "", 0L, password);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      _log.error(e, e);
    }
    throw new AuthException(e);
  }

  public int authenticateByScreenName(long companyId, String screenName, String password, Map<String, String[]> headerMap, Map<String, String[]> parameterMap)
    throws AuthException
  {
    try
    {
      return authenticate(companyId, "", screenName, 0L, password);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      _log.error(e, e);
    }
    throw new AuthException(e);
  }

  public int authenticateByUserId(long companyId, long userId, String password, Map<String, String[]> headerMap, Map<String, String[]> parameterMap)
    throws AuthException
  {
    try
    {
      return authenticate(companyId, "", "", userId, password);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      _log.error(e, e);
    }
    throw new AuthException(e);
  }

  protected int authenticate(long companyId, String emailAddress, String screenName, long userId, String password)
    throws Exception
  {
    if (!PortalLDAPUtil.isAuthEnabled(companyId)) {
      if (_log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        _log.debug("Authenticator is not enabled");
      }

      return 1;
    }

    if (_log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      _log.debug("Authenticator is enabled");
    }

    if (authenticateOmniadmin(companyId, emailAddress, screenName, userId) == 1)
    {
      return 1;
    }

    String baseDN = PrefsPropsUtil.getString(companyId, "ldap.base.dn");

    LdapContext ctx = PortalLDAPUtil.getContext(companyId);

    if (ctx == null) {
      return authenticateRequired(companyId, userId, emailAddress, -1);
    }

    String filter = PortalLDAPUtil.getAuthSearchFilter(companyId, emailAddress, screenName, String.valueOf(userId));
    try
    {
      SearchControls cons = new SearchControls(2, 1L, 0, null, false, false);

      NamingEnumeration enu = ctx.search(baseDN, filter, cons);
      SearchResult result;
      if (enu.hasMoreElements()) {
        if (_log.isDebugEnabled()) {
          _log.debug("Search filter returned at least one result");
        }

        result = (SearchResult)enu.nextElement();

        String fullUserDN = PortalLDAPUtil.getNameInNamespace(companyId, result);

        Attributes attrs = PortalLDAPUtil.getUserAttributes(companyId, ctx, fullUserDN);

        LDAPAuthResult ldapAuthResult = authenticate(ctx, companyId, attrs, fullUserDN, password);

        String errorMessage = ldapAuthResult.getErrorMessage();

        if (errorMessage != null) {
          if (errorMessage.indexOf(PrefsPropsUtil.getString(companyId, "ldap.error.user.lockout")) != -1)
          {
            throw new UserLockoutException();
          }
          if (errorMessage.indexOf(PrefsPropsUtil.getString(companyId, "ldap.error.password.expired")) != -1)
          {
            throw new PasswordExpiredException();
          }
        }

        if (!ldapAuthResult.isAuthenticated()) {
          int i = authenticateRequired(companyId, userId, emailAddress, -1);
          return i;
        }
        User user = PortalLDAPUtil.importLDAPUser(companyId, ctx, attrs, password, true);

        String resultCode = ldapAuthResult.getResponseControl();

        if (resultCode.equals("2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.4")) {
          UserLocalServiceUtil.updatePasswordReset(user.getUserId(), true);
        }
        else if (resultCode.equals("2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.5"))
        {
          UserLocalServiceUtil.updatePasswordReset(user.getUserId(), true);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        if (_log.isDebugEnabled()) {
          _log.debug("Search filter did not return any results");
        }

        result = authenticateRequired(companyId, userId, emailAddress, 0);
        return result;
      }
      enu.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      _log.error("Problem accessing LDAP server: " + e.getMessage());

      if (authenticateRequired(companyId, userId, emailAddress, -1) == -1)
      {
        throw e;
      }
    }
    finally {
      if (ctx != null) {
        ctx.close();
      }
    }

    return 1;
  }

  protected LDAPAuthResult authenticate(LdapContext ctx, long companyId, Attributes attrs, String userDN, String password)
    throws Exception
  {
    LDAPAuthResult ldapAuthResult = new LDAPAuthResult();

    String authMethod = PrefsPropsUtil.getString(companyId, "ldap.auth.method");

    InitialLdapContext innerCtx = null;

    if (authMethod.equals("bind")) {
      try {
        Hashtable env = ctx.getEnvironment();

        env.put("java.naming.security.principal", userDN);
        env.put("java.naming.security.credentials", password);
        env.put("java.naming.referral", PrefsPropsUtil.getString(companyId, "ldap.referral"));

        env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool", "false");

        innerCtx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

        Control[] responseControls = innerCtx.getResponseControls();

        ldapAuthResult.setAuthenticated(true);
        ldapAuthResult.setResponseControl(responseControls);
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        if (_log.isDebugEnabled()) {
          _log.debug("Failed to bind to the LDAP server with userDN " + userDN + " and password " + password);
        }

        _log.error("Failed to bind to the LDAP server: " + e.getMessage());

        ldapAuthResult.setAuthenticated(false);
        ldapAuthResult.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
      }
      finally {
        if (innerCtx != null) {
          innerCtx.close();
        }
      }
    }
    else if (authMethod.equals("password-compare")) {
      Attribute userPassword = attrs.get("userPassword");

      if (userPassword != null) {
        String ldapPassword = new String((byte[])(byte[])userPassword.get());

        String encryptedPassword = password;

        String algorithm = PrefsPropsUtil.getString(companyId, "ldap.auth.password.encryption.algorithm");

        if (Validator.isNotNull(algorithm)) {
          encryptedPassword = "{" + algorithm + "}" + PwdEncryptor.encrypt(algorithm, password, ldapPassword);
        }

        if (ldapPassword.equals(encryptedPassword)) {
          ldapAuthResult.setAuthenticated(true);
        }
        else {
          ldapAuthResult.setAuthenticated(false);

          if (_log.isWarnEnabled()) {
            _log.warn("Passwords do not match for userDN " + userDN);
          }
        }
      }

    }

    return ldapAuthResult;
  }

  protected int authenticateOmniadmin(long companyId, String emailAddress, String screenName, long userId)
    throws Exception
  {
    if (PropsValues.AUTH_PIPELINE_ENABLE_LIFERAY_CHECK) {
      if (userId > 0L) {
        if (OmniadminUtil.isOmniadmin(userId)) {
          return 1;
        }
      }
      else if (Validator.isNotNull(emailAddress)) {
        try {
          User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByEmailAddress(companyId, emailAddress);

          if (OmniadminUtil.isOmniadmin(user.getUserId()))
            return 1;
        }
        catch (NoSuchUserException nsue)
        {
        }
      }
      else if (Validator.isNotNull(screenName)) {
        try {
          User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByScreenName(companyId, screenName);

          if (OmniadminUtil.isOmniadmin(user.getUserId())) {
            return 1;
          }
        }
        catch (NoSuchUserException nsue)
        {
        }
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }

  protected int authenticateRequired(long companyId, long userId, String emailAddress, int failureCode)
    throws Exception
  {
    if (PrefsPropsUtil.getBoolean(companyId, "ldap.auth.required"))
    {
      return failureCode;
    }

    return 1;
  }
}
```

Is there anyone who can help me to modify this class ( exactly **authenticateByEmailAddress** methode)   in order to check the user's group in ldap in login state

meaning in login methode check user only in :

**testGroup1 and testGroup2** and not in all locations in ldap

Comment: Could you reword your post, that it contains a question? And what about changing the _Authentication Search Filter_ to include only those from the two groups?

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have updated my question but I still have the same problem to modify authenticateByEmailAddress methode  in LDAPAuth class