# liferay 5.2 ldap login method check users in only specifics group

Tags: ldap, liferay

I used liferay 5.2 and I can integrate ldap correctly with  liferay and I activated ldap in login.

and I arrived to import only users from ldap wich exists in my groups using this configuration :

[image]

[image]

[image]

my problem now is when I try to login in liferay 
it checks user if exist or not in all locations in ldap

**I want in login state to check user if exist or not only in my specifics group which is exist in my configuration.**

meaning in login state  check user only in :

**testGroup1 and testGroup2**  and not in all locations in ldap

Comment: is it the best way to override login method using action hook
or just adding some configuration in portal-ext.properties

Comment: Possible duplicate of [liferay disable import users after login or check existing users in some groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361468/liferay-disable-import-users-after-login-or-check-existing-users-in-some-groups)